# Copy Google talk chat messages to clipboard

Tags: google-talk

I got some message over talk that I want to copy to clipboard. That is not possible. Long pressing does nothing. Tried on 4.0.4-ICS and 2.3.7-Gingerbread without succes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Google Talk and have a GMail account, your chats are automatically logged in GMail. If you search for label:chat, you should be able to find that conversation and copy the text from your GMail application.

BTW, I think that the fact that you can't copy the text from the chat app really needs to be fixed.

Comment: the text was a wifi passphrase at a friends location. I had to switch back&forth between wifi settings view and talk...